# Regex not catching continuous credit card number

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My regex matches when the number has `<space>` or it has `"-"` if all 16 digit card number does not have `<space>` or `"-"` then it does not match.

```
(4\d{3}[\s\-\\]\d{4}[\s\-\\]\d{4}[\s\-\\]\d{4})
```

It matches `4444-0000-0000 0000`
But it does not match `4444000000000000

Comment: Actually, I don't think it will catch what you typed there.  You're missing a hyphen in that first series.

Comment: Oh I corrected it. Here is the option I am looking for.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/R3Be0s/1

Comment: @STLDev https://regex101.com/r/R3Be0s/1

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew please https://regex101.com/r/R3Be0s/1

Comment: Why have you escaped the closing bracket `]` of the character class? It should be `[\s-]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the separators optional by coding a `?` after the character class:

```
\b(4\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4})\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/6MHGptXE9kDG4e).

I added word boundaries `\b` at either end to it doesn't match for example the first 16 digits of 40001111222233338.

btw, you can code it more briefly by repeating `[\s-]?\d{4}` 3 times, like this:

```
\b(4\d{3}([\s-]?\d{4}){3})\b
```

Comment: Given `\s` will match newline or tab, using a literal space is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @Nick I agree totoaly and noticed that too, but I wanted to make the minimum change possible to fix the problem. I'll suggest that tho, thx.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you included a capture group.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I added a group to repeat it. I didn’t make it non-capturing because a) I couldn’t be bothered typing `?:`, b) regex is hard enough to read anyway, so don’t add what you don’t need to, and c) the “performance” difference while there is so tiny you would have great difficulty measuring it. All in all, unless there is a pressing need, for example multiple captured groups that I want to keep numbered 1-n, I never use non-capturing groups.

Comment: That's interesting (especially a) :-)). Another perspective is that if one uses a capture group when a non-capture group would do, the reader may be led to believe you will be using the content of the capture group, and look for something that is not there. I doubt that it makes any difference (especially if you are known to your colleagues as the guy who refuses to use non-capture groups).